# Can we use height of image extracted from JQuery inside media query some how?

Tags: jquery, html, css, media-queries

Is it possible to use a java script variable which has height of the image in media query ??

my javascript code is like this

```
$(document).on('click', '.transparent-btns_nav',function(event){

    //alert('clicked');
    var images = $('.rslides ').find('img');
images.each(function(){ // jQuery each loops over a jQuery obj

    var h = $(this).outerHeight(true);// $(this) is the current image
    var w =  $(this).outerWidth(true);
    //alert('source:'+$(this).attr('src'));
    //alert('alto: '+h);
    if( h <290)
    {  
        var m = 290-h;
        m = m/2;
        var n = 290 - w ;
        n = n/2;
        //alert('less height');
        $(this).css('margin-top', +m + "px");
       $(this).css('margin-bottom', +m + "px");

    }

});
});
```

and my media query code is some thing like this

```
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 320px) 
and (orientation : portrait) {
#bg {
 max-height:290px;
 height:290px;
 margin:auto;
 margin-top:auto;
 overflow:hidden;
}
.thumb{
margin-top:-60px;

}
}
```

What is happening the media query in portrait mode will add -60px top-margin . but then the java script adds some margin to top and bottom when the image height is smaller .
What  happening is that the margin at top is becoming too much with java script and media query both for the image which are smaller than the outer div size .

Can any one tell me if I can use the h variable from java script into media Query to check if the size of the image is smaller then not add -60px top-margin .

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The precise answer to your question is no, you can't use a JavaScript variable inside a media query.

But there is a way to do what you want.

If the image is small, then add a CSS class to it using JS/jQuery, e.g.

```
$('.thumb').addClass('small');
```

Then in your media query:

```
@media only screen and (min-device-width : 320px) and (orientation : portrait) {
  .thumb:not(.small) {
    margin-top: -60px;
  }
}
```

What's happening here is that the CSS margin is only added to thumbs that haven't been earmarked by JS as being small.

Comment: but In my website its adding the class even if the images are greater .

Comment: For example look at this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/4PQLr/14/   the class is being added even if the images are smaller than the if statement. Can you explain me this

Comment: Change `$('.thumb').addClass('small')` to `$(this).addClass('small')` so that your selector matches only the image you are measuring.